# Change the functionality of wordpress users module in admin

Tags: customization, users, user-roles, core

I want to restrict wordpress admin to view all users in user list.

For say, I have created custom roles (company users, employee). A company user type role can have multiple employees.

I want wordpress admin to only view company users.

I got, `args` in    `function prepare_items()`  inside  `WP_Users_List_Table` class can filter this. So have tried to override this in my theme's functions.php.

```
function my_prepare_items(){

    //my custom code goes here

}
add_action( 'prepare_items', 'my_prepare_items' );
```

But it's not working. How and where I can override this functionality without touching core wordpress methods?

EDIT :
This I want in admin UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply click the role links on the top side of the table? They are exactly there for filtering that list...

Comment: Its okay but I want to show only one role and dont show other roles

Comment: Does it have to be non-hackable (and every other role just locked away) or would it be enough to point the menu link to exactly this role filter per default?